# Wordpress online pharmacy hack?

Tags: web-application, attack-prevention, spam, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Protecting WordPress installations](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/477/protecting-wordpress-installations)

anybody knows how to protect your WordPress website from online pharmacy spam, even after deleting all spam files and deleting spam records from DB it returns back after a while

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. What WP version, what files/records, etc..

Comment: @Mena are you talking about spam posts / comments being posted to the blog?

Comment: @Mena - have you looked at this question. Think it may be a duplicate. http://security.stackexchange.com/q/477/485

Answer (score 6):

If your referring to spam comments then you might want to check out the [WordPress Akismet plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/akismet/) which checks comments against the [Akismet](https://akismet.com/) web service to see if they look like spam or not.
Its very good and in a lot of cases eliminates all potential spam. I use it on my blog and in a year its blocked ~4,000 spam comments.

Comment: +1. I can recommend Akismet aswell. Too bad it is not free unless you keep your hosting at *.wordpress.com

Comment: It's can be free if just a personal blog depending on how much you wish to contribute its between $0-120yr. For business its $5/mo which is still not bad.