# Malicious php scripts in word press theme folder?

Tags: php, injection, wordpress

I am running a server on Ubuntu 10.04 running a word press website, and recently a virus scan revealed that I have several malicious scripts sitting in the word press folder. In particular they are in the cache and temp folder of a theme that I'm currently using.

I opened them with VIM and read through them, they are certainly bots and spamware, one of them is even called c99 injecktor. I am very interested in how these scripts can be injected into these folders, and what actions I should take upon discovering them. Should I simply delete them?

Also, is the injection caused by security flaw of word press, or should I be worry about anything else other than getting a more up-to-date version of word press in my new server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were most likely compromised through a vulnerable installation or theme, probably through something that is now known and fixed.

First, once you've been compromised a little, it's best to assume you've been compromised a lot and start fresh. Read up on the answers to this question: [My server's been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/q/218005/3139)

Second, besides updating to the latest versions, you can take extra steps to help prevent damage when some part of your Wordpress install has a vulnerability. Read up on more from this question:
[How can I protect a WordPress installation?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/477/836)

Comment: Coolbeans, thanks for the info they are very helpful. Yes I am now working on launching a new instance of my server :)