# How Do I Secure Apache Web Server

Tags: apache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apache Server Hardening](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/77/apache-server-hardening)

I'm going to make a web server on Apache 2.

What are the security issue I will be looking at? And how do I secure it?

I have been reading news about DDOS attacks, web server hacks.

(I'm very new to Linux, I have started learning Linux 8 months ago.)